# Expose a collection of enums (flags) in Visual Studio designer

Tags: .net, visual-studio, winforms

I've got an enum of types of data that might be shown in a .NET Forms control and I want to provide an interface for consumers of the control to filter some of the types (set some of the flags).  A bit field seems the logical way to do this, unfortunately, the enum starts at 0 rather than 1 (0, 1, 2, 4, 8, ...) and can't be changed.

How can I expose this set of flags so that it can be easily configured programmatically or through the Visual Studio designer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to write a `UITypeEditor` to do the work, and associate it with the property via `[EditorAttribute]`.

**edit** now with example - a fairly long one, I'm afraid - but most of the code can be shared between types, fortunately.

You can't use a single composite enum value because of the zero - so here I'm using a `HashSet<T>` to hold the selected enums - fairly easy to re-work to `List<T>` if you have .NET 2.0/3.0, though.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing.Design;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;

public class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        Values = new HashSet<MyEnum>();
    }
    [Editor(typeof(MyEnumSetEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(MyEnumSetConverter))]
    public HashSet<MyEnum> Values { get; set; }
}

public enum MyEnum
{  // numbers as per the question...
    A = 0, B = 1, C = 2, D = 4, E = 8
}
class MyEnumSetEditor : EnumSetEditor<MyEnum> { }
class MyEnumSetConverter : EnumSetConverter<MyEnum> { }

// from here down is shared between types
abstract class EnumSetConverter<T> : TypeConverter where T : struct
{
    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        return destinationType == typeof(string) || base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
    }
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if(destinationType == typeof(string))
        {
            HashSet<T> set = (HashSet<T>)value;
            if (set == null) return "(null)";

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (T item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
            {
                if (set.Contains(item))
                {
                    if (sb.Length > 0) sb.Append(", ");
                    sb.Append(item);
                }
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}

public abstract class EnumSetEditor<T> : UITypeEditor where T : struct
{
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.DropDown;
    }
    public override bool IsDropDownResizable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        IWindowsFormsEditorService svc = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)
            provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));
        HashSet<T> set = value as HashSet<T>;
        if (svc != null && set != null)
        {
            UserControl ctrl = new UserControl();
            CheckedListBox clb = new CheckedListBox();
            clb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
            foreach (T item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
            {
                clb.Items.Add(item, set.Contains(item));
            }
            ctrl.Controls.Add(clb);
            ctrl.Controls.Add(btn);
            btn.Text = "OK";
            btn.Click += delegate
            {
                set.Clear();
                foreach (T item in clb.CheckedItems)
                {
                    set.Add(item);
                }
                svc.CloseDropDown();
            };
            svc.DropDownControl(ctrl);
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow.  Marc - I really appreciate you taking the time to do this.

Comment: @Marc: Found this one after a search, but I cannot get it to persist the changes in the property editor back to the .designer.cs file. Any hints?

Comment: @MarcGravell: Please... ?

Comment: @HeartWare I haven't done much with type-descriptor code in 5 years... I simply cannot remember

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: the editor control appeared to work, but the values wouldn't persist. Building on Marc's answer and some further research I've now got it running. 
Although I needed this feature for editing my own controls at DesignTime, I tested it using a demo project with a PropertyGrid control after reading the following quote from [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171840.aspx):

> When you develop your custom UITypeEditor, it is recommended that you
>   set the build number to increment with each build. This prevents
>   older, cached versions of your UITypeEditor from being created in the
>   design environment.

I think that was actually an issue that caused problems while trying to implement Marc's solution. Testing in a separate project is also helpful because you can use Step-By-Step-Debugging to see what happens in the control, editor and converter.

The basic steps are:

- Create the type (here: **MyFlags**) and the property (here: **MyProperty**), adding some extra attributes to the
  latter.
- Implement the control (here: **EnumEditorControl**) to be used for editing.
- Implement an `UITypeEditor` class (here: **EnumEditor**); this is connected to the property using the `Editor` attribute. It is also creates and manages the instance of our *EnumEditorControl*.
- Implement a `TypeConverter` class (here: **EnumConverter**); this is also connected to the property using an attribute (`TypeConverter`) and handles converting the value into a string for display in the property grid.

And now a walkthrough with the relevant code snippets:

1. Define an `Enum` using the `Flags` attribute.

   ```
   <Flags>
   Public Enum MyFlags
       Flag1 = 2 ^ 0
       Flag2 = 2 ^ 1
       Flag3 = 2 ^ 2
   End Enum
   ```
2. Define the property for the custom control.

   ```
   Public Property MyProperty() As MyFlags
       ...
   End Property
   ```

This property will later have attributes added to it once we've created the other components we need (see #6).

3. Create the desired control that is to be used for editing the
   property.

   ```
   Imports System.Windows.Forms.Design
   Public Class EnumEditorControl(Of T As Structure)
       Public Sub New(value As Long, editorService As IWindowsFormsEditorService)
           'This call is required by the Windows.Forms Form Designer.
           InitializeComponent()

           _value = value
           _editorService = editorService

           For Each item As Long In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(T))
               Me.CheckedListBox1.Items.Add([Enum].GetName(GetType(T), item), (_value And item) = item)
           Next

       End Sub

       Private _value As Long
       Public Property Value As Long
           Get
               Return _value
           End Get
           Set(value As Long)
               _value = value
           End Set
       End Property
       Private _editorService As IWindowsFormsEditorService

       Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
           Dim v As Long = 0
           For Each item As String In Me.CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems
               v = (v Or [Enum].Parse(GetType(T), item))
           Next
           _value = v
           Me._editorService.CloseDropDown()
       End Sub
   End Class
   ```

The above is the class' code without the *designer.vb* portions. The important parts are: a constructor with `value` and `editorService` parameters, filling the control with the currently selected values (in the constructor) and implementing a "commit action" where the `Value` property of the control is updated (depending on the selection made) and finally calling `Me._editorService.CloseDropDown()`.

4. Define a generic UITypeEditor.

   ```
   Imports System.ComponentModel
   Imports System.Drawing.Design
   Imports System.Windows.Forms.Design

   Public Class EnumEditor(Of T As Structure)
       Inherits UITypeEditor

       Public Overrides Function GetEditStyle(context As ITypeDescriptorContext) As UITypeEditorEditStyle
           Return UITypeEditorEditStyle.DropDown
       End Function
       Public Overrides ReadOnly Property IsDropDownResizable() As Boolean
           Get
               Return True
           End Get
       End Property
       Public Overrides Function EditValue(context As ITypeDescriptorContext, provider As IServiceProvider, value As Object) As Object
           Dim svc As IWindowsFormsEditorService = DirectCast(provider.GetService(GetType(IWindowsFormsEditorService)), IWindowsFormsEditorService)
           Dim items As Long = CLng(value)
           If svc IsNot Nothing Then
               Dim c As New EnumEditorControl(Of T)(value, svc)

               svc.DropDownControl(c)

               value = c.Value
           End If

           Return CType(value, T)
       End Function
   End Class
   ```

The core part here is the override of `EditValue` where an instance of our editor control (see #3) is created and shown using `svc.DropDownControl(c)`. And, finally, retrieving the selected value from our control's property and returning it.

5. Define a generic *TypeConverter* used for converting the actual value into a string representation to be used in the property explorer.
       Imports System.ComponentModel
       Imports System.Drawing.Design
       Imports System.Text
       Imports System.Windows.Forms.Design

   ```
   Class EnumConverter(Of T As Structure)
       Inherits TypeConverter

       Public Overrides Function CanConvertTo(context As ITypeDescriptorContext, destinationType As Type) As Boolean
           Return destinationType = GetType(String) OrElse MyBase.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType)
       End Function
       Public Overrides Function ConvertTo(context As ITypeDescriptorContext, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo, value As Object, destinationType As Type) As Object
           If destinationType = GetType(String) Then
               Dim items As Integer = CLng(value)

               If items = 0 Then
                   Return ""
               End If

               Dim values As New List(Of String)

               For Each item As Integer In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(T))
                   If (items And item) = item Then
                       values.Add([Enum].GetName(GetType(T), item))
                   End If
               Next
               Return String.Join(", ", values)
           End If

           Return MyBase.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType)
       End Function
   End Class
   ```
6. Tie it all together by adding the following attributes to the defined property (see #2).

   ```
   <Browsable(True),
   DefaultValue(MyFlags.Flag1),
   Editor(GetType(EnumEditor(Of MyFlags)), 
   GetType(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor)),
   TypeConverter(GetType(EnumConverter(Of MyFlags)))
   >
   Public Property MyProperty() As MyFlags
       ...
   End Property
   ```

Note: Referring to the "zero value" mentioned in the question: this solution does not take that into account, but it could easily be modified to do so.